# Syntax error after "read" only when script invoked with "bash -s <script"

Tags: bash

I have two scripts and both are in different servers and I use these for automating a small process.

script1 starts script2 using command

```
ssh -i /pathToKeyFile/keyfile.pem user@server2 'bash -s < /pathToScriptFile/script2.sh'
```

In script2.sh I have a "case" question:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask to start up JBOSS
read -p "DB restore completed. Start JBOSS and FACADE (y/n)" startJBOSS
case "$startJBOSS" in
        y|Y ) echo "Starting JBOSS and FACADE";;
        n|N ) echo "Stopping here"
        exit;;
        * ) echo "Invalid option..."
        exit;;
esac

echo "More commands here"
exit
```

So when I execute script1.sh it works fine and starst script2 on remote server.
But script2 fails to error

```
bash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: line 5: ` y|Y ) echo "Starting JBOSS and FACADE";;'
```

If I execute script2.sh directly from remote server it works as expected.

I also tried so that both script files are located in one server. Of cource in this case commant to start script2.sh is different, but in this case both works again as expected.

I cannot figure out why script2.sh fails when it is started from and other script located in an other server. I assume that script2.sh "code" is correct as it works when ran separately.

Comment: BTW, I realize that the title updates take into account information where it wasn't easy to know what was relevant until *after* you had an answer. The purpose of updating the title to follow the actual cause is to help that title be useful to others with the same underlying problem (which is general to use of `read` when the script itself is coming from stdin), whether or not they have the same incidental surrounding details (such as whether it's another script performing that invocation, whether it's over SSH, whether the next line is `case`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `read` reads from stdin -- the same place your code is coming from.

Thus, instead of reading a line from the user, it reads a line from the file of source, consuming the `case` command, leaving the rest of the source file syntactically invalid.

---

#### Simple Answer: Don't Do That.

`bash -s <filename` makes sense when the `<filename` is coming from somewhere not accessible to the copy of `bash` (like the other side of the SSH connection, or a file that can only be read by a different user), but that's not the case for your example. Thus, you can just stop using the `-s` argument and the redirection:

```
ssh -i /pathToKeyFile/keyfile.pem user@server2 'bash /pathToScriptFile/script2.sh'
```

---

#### ...or make the prompt conditional...

Another approach is to make the `read` conditional on there actually being a user listening at the TTY:

```
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then  # test whether FD 0, stdin, is a TTY
  read -p "DB restore completed. Start JBOSS and FACADE (y/n)" startJBOSS
else
  startJBOSS=y       # no TTY, so assume yes
fi
```

---

#### ...or make the prompt read from `/dev/tty`, and make sure SSH passes it through.

An alternate approach is to read from `/dev/tty` explicitly, and then to arrange for that to be valid in the context of your script by passing appropriate arguments to `ssh`:

```
if read -p "DB restore completed. Start JBOSS and FACADE (y/n)" startJBOSS </dev/tty; then
  : "read $startJBOSS from user successfully" # <- will be logged if run with set -x
else
  echo "Unable to read result from user; is this being run with a TTY?" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

...and then, on the other side, using the `-t` argument to SSH, to force there to be a TTY (if one is available to SSH itself; if not, *it* won't have a means to read from the user out-of-band either):

```
ssh -t -i /pathToKeyFile/keyfile.pem user@server2 'bash -s < /pathToScriptFile/script2.sh'
```

Comment: And finally, it's best to run the script directly so it can decide what shell it wants: `ssh -i /pathToKeyFile/keyfile.pem user@server2 /pathToScriptFile/script2.sh`

Comment: Good point. That said, if one's going to do that, it should be really renamed to not have an extension at all.